# Generic Function Of Stuct Declaration

Tags: c

I have built a generic Binary Search Tree.

```
typedef struct Tree {
    void* data;
    struct Tree *left;
    struct Tree *right;
}Tree;
```

And two functions that create a Tree with different data type variables.

```
Tree* GetNewTreeInt(){
    Tree* newTree = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    *((int*)newTree->data);
    newTree->left = newTree->right = NULL;
    return newTree;
}

Tree* GetNewTreeChar(){
    Tree* newTree = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    *((char*)newTree->data);
    newTree->left = newTree->right = NULL;
    return newTree;
}
```

I have tried to create a generic function that store the function by address

```
Tree* CreateTree();

    int main() {
    void* root;
    scanf("%d", &choose);
    if(choose==0){
        Tree* CreateTree=GetNewTreeInt();
        (Tree*)root=CreateTree();
    }
```

But I keep getting the following error:  called object type "Tree*" (aka 'struct Tree*') is not a function or function pointer

Comment: You cast belongs on the other side of the assignment...`root = (void*)CreateTree()`

Comment: The line `*((int*)newTree->data);` has no effect making `GetNewTreeInt` and `GetNewTreeChar` exactly the same functions.

Comment: @nwellnhof initializing of the variables will be done later after input from the user

Comment: @user590028 I did as you wrote but then for the assignment of the pointer function I get "Non-object time 'Tree*()' is not assignable"

Comment: PaulPro & Dmitri both answered correctly, though I would add that you should be using `Tree* GetNewTreeInt(void)` not `Tree* GetNewTreeInt()`.  The former means the function takes no arguments.  The latter means the function can take any arguments.  The pointer declaration then becomes `Tree * (*CreateTree)(void);`

Comment: @BrianMcFarland Thanks for the note. I added the `void` into my answer.

Comment: assignment to void pointer root should be done: $root=CreateTree();$ or casting is needed? $(Tree*)root=CreateTree();$

Comment: @gbox The cast isn't needed to assign to root -- you can assign any (non-function) pointer to a `void*` variable.  The cast would be needed when you dereference it later, though.  In this case I don't see why you don't declare `root` as `Tree*` instead, though.

Comment: 1) the code should always check the returned value from malloc (and family) to assure the operation was successful.  2) casting the returned value from malloc (and family), in C,  has several problems and should not be performed.

Comment: @Dmitri when trying to assign an address of int type to 
(Tree*)(*root)->data=&tNumber; I get "Member Reference type 'void' is not a pointer'

Comment: @gbox `root` is a `void*`, so the type of `(*root)` is `void`, so the `->data` doesn't make sense.  I suspect you want `((Tree*)root)->data=&tNumber;` (though make sure `tNumber` will exist as long as the node and isn't being reused for the other nodes).

Comment: @Dmitri so when creating a pointer from a type, let say int, we get a storage for an address, and when accessing the memory that the pointer points at via (*pointer) the data type of that memory is the same type of the pointer?
Where can I learn more about pointers? thanks a lot for all the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you were trying to use a function pointer. To do that you would need to declare a function pointer to a function which return a `Tree*`, not a `Tree*` directly:

```
if(choose==0) {
    Tree* (*CreateTree)(void);
    CreateTree = &GetNewTreeInt;
}
```

However, your two functions are identical, since the line `*((int*)newTree->data);` has no side-effects. You could just create a function like this instead:

```
Tree* GetNewTreeInt(void){
    Tree* newTree = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    newTree->left = newTree->right = NULL;
    return newTree;
}
```

It's when you access `tree->data` that you need to cast the `void *` to a pointer of the type you know it contains. If you don't know what type of tree you have externally, you should add another field to your struct which signifies which type of data is stored. If you're only storing small data types like `int` and `char` I would recommend using a union instead of a void pointer, since a union will store the data inside the Tree in memory. Either way you'll still need something in your tree to indicate what type of data its storing.

```
typedef struct Tree {

    // 0 means there is an int in tree->data.i,
    // 1 means there is a char in tree->data.c
    int type; 

    union {
        int i;
        char c;
    } data;

    struct Tree *left;
    struct Tree *right;

} Tree;
```

Then your two functions become:

```
Tree* GetNewTreeInt(void){
    Tree* newTree = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    newTree->type = 0;
    newTree->data.i = 0; // Set an initial value
    newTree->left = newTree->right = NULL;
    return newTree;
}

Tree* GetNewTreeChar(void){
    Tree* newTree = (Tree*)malloc(sizeof(Tree));
    newTree->type = 1;
    newTree->data.c = '\0'; // Set an initial value
    newTree->left = newTree->right = NULL;
    return newTree;
}
```

And you can use a function pointer just like this:

```
if(choose==0) {
    Tree* (*CreateTree)(void);
    CreateTree = &GetNewTreeInt;

    Tree* tree = CreateTree();
    tree->data.i = 7;
}
```

Each tree will have either a `data.i` or `data.c`, but not both, later when you're traversing your trees you can check their type to find out which:

```
if ( tree->type == 0 ) {
    int data = tree->data.i;
} else if ( tree->type == 1 ) {
    char data = tree->data.c;
}
```

**EDIT**

If you really want to use a `void *`, you can still add the `int type` to your struct, and when traversing you could do something like this:

```
if ( tree->type == 0 ) {
    int data = *(int *)tree->data;
} else if ( tree->type == 1 ) {
    char data = *(char *)tree->data;
}
```

Comment: as for the variable type I can not use union, but thanks for the explanation on union.
As for the function pointer, So what I need to do is to declare the pointer function inside main and the assign it with a function?
Tree* (*CreateTree)(); mean that it a Tree type pointer and that it store an address  that is way it is (*CreateTree) and not just CreateTree?

Comment: @gbox If you can't use `union` you can still do this by adding a `type` to your struct to identify what type of data is in `tree->data`. See the **EDIT** section at the very bottom of my post

Comment: `Tree* (*CreateTree)(void);` means that `CreateTree` is a pointer to a function where that function takes no arguments and returns a `Tree *`. The `*` in `(*CreateTree)` is there to indicate that `CreateTree` is a pointer itself (a pointer to a function).

Comment: as for the void I understand, I do not get wait it is (*CreateTree) and not (CreateTree)

Comment: @gbox Maybe it would help you understand if I change `CreateTree = GetNewTreeInt;` to `CreateTree = &GetNewTreeInt;`. They mean the same thing in C, when `GetNewTreeInt` is a function.

Comment: can is the last Edit you wrote can be inside the struct?

Comment: @gbox No, that's the logic that you use when you have a `tree` and you want to access its data, but you don't know if it contains an `int` or a `char`. If you add `int type; ` to your struct, you can assign to that when you set `data` and then use it to determine the type of `data` later.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
Tree* CreateTree();
```

..declares a function `CreateTree` that returns a `Tree*`, without fully defining the function (no function body, just a prototype).  Whereas this:

```
Tree* CreateTree=GetNewTreeInt();
```

declares a variable of type `Tree*` named `CreateTree`, and calls the `GetNewTreeInt()` function assigning its return value to `CreateTree`.  This gives you your error since you've already declared a function with the same name.

If you want `CreateTree` to be a function pointer, and to point it at the `GetNewTreeInt` function, you need to declare it as (either globally or within `main`, not both):

```
Tree *(*CreateTree)();
```

..and then point it at `GetNewTreeInt` like this:

```
CreateTree = GetNewTreeInt;
```

..and then you can call the function through the pointer with just `CreateTree()` as with a normal function, eg.:

```
root = CreateTree();
```

If you want a typedef of the function pointer type, you can do that as follows:

```
typedef Tree *(*CreateTreeFuncType)();
```

...and declare `CreateTree` as:

```
CreateTreeFuncType CreateTree;
```

instead of using the function pointer syntax mentioned earlier.